# C Web Server - Print incoming data?

Tags: c, webserver

This C Web Server will print out

```
 got connection
```

via terminal.. for each serve to the web.

But I would like it to also print out all of the incoming raw data.

such as URL, CLIENT IP.. whatever it has received basically. 
( no sortment necessary. just raw data )

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h> 
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <err.h>

char response[] = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n"
"Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n\r\n"
"test\r\n";

int main()
{
  int one = 1, client_fd;
  struct sockaddr_in svr_addr, cli_addr;
  socklen_t sin_len = sizeof(cli_addr);

  int sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
  if (sock < 0)
    err(1, "can't open socket");

  setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &one, sizeof(int));

  int port = 81;
  svr_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  svr_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
  svr_addr.sin_port = htons(port);

  if (bind(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &svr_addr, sizeof(svr_addr)) == -1) {
    close(sock);
    err(1, "Can't bind");
  }

  listen(sock, 5);
  while (1) {
    client_fd = accept(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, &sin_len);
    printf("got connection\n");

    if (client_fd == -1) {
      perror("Can't accept");
      continue;
    }

    write(client_fd, response, sizeof(response) - 1); /*-1:'\0'*/
    close(client_fd);
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself?

Comment: I do not know anything about C. I only know how to compile it for now. I found this on the web.

Comment: I know the whatever the code is.. it has to go under.. **printf("got connection\n");** but I know NOTHING about C.

Comment: Then either learn C, or find an existing utility/piece of code to do what you want.

Comment: @Mat, The only way I can learn C is if this program printed out the raw data for me. Then I could go researching on how to sort out the raw data ( parse URI from it.. etc.. )

Comment: "The only way I can learn C is if this program printed out the raw data for me." - sorry that makes no sense at all. If you want to update this program yourself to make it do other stuff, you need to learn C first. This site is not a code factory, nor a tutorial service. There are tons of resource available online & offline about C for you to learn it.

Comment: @Mat, For me to have reasons to devote my time to learn something.. that something first has to provide evidence that it CAN be useful to me. Once I see it print the raw data.. I will have reasons to believe it CAN be useful to me.

Comment: @vern0: So you bother us an take **our** time instead to solve your problem. Aparently you already have an example which shows that learning C is useful: to fix that snippet you found somewhere! If you want other's to do your job: hire a freelancer!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can receive the client information by using `inet_ntoa`.

Just use `inet_ntoa(cli_addr.sin_addr)`. The incoming raw data you could easily catch with `recv`, but then you've to set the Sockets to Non-Blocking. Any information (url, user agent) will be saved into the recv buffer.

Usage of `printf("[%s] - Connected to server\n", inet_ntoa(cli_addr.sin_addr));` will print the IP Addr.

Hope it helps!

Comment: How can that be put inside of a **printf("\n");** ?

Comment: How do you mean that exactly?

Comment: Suppose I never learned anything about C.. All I know is PHP and so on.. how can I make it "**print_r()**" that stuff ? the raw data..

Comment: c.c: In function ‘main’:
c.c:41:54: error: ‘client_addr’ undeclared (first use in this function)
     printf("[%s] - Connected to server\n", inet_ntoa(client_addr.sin_addr));
                                                      ^
c.c:41:54: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in

Comment: Change client_addr to cli_addr. Better learn C first before writing a server.

Comment: @vern0: We are neither a coding nor a tutoring service. If you want to modify C code, **learn the language**.

Comment: @Olaf, what are you guys ?